# Find the packges installed by a task with tasksel

Tags: debian, package-management

If I install a GUI with `tasksel` it installs some packages but it doesn't remove them all when it removes the GUI.

I tried to use the `tasksel` option to find something but it only shows `task-cinnamon-desktop`, for example for cinnamon:

```
tasksel --task-packages cinnamon-desktop
task-cinnamon-desktop
```

How can I find all the packages installed by a task?

I use Debian 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to clean up after `tasksel` installed a package, you need to determine what actually happened as a result of that installation, and that’s highly context-dependent. There are logs however; if you check `/var/log/apt/history.log`, you should find the details of what `tasksel` installed, and you’ll be able to use that to remove all the packages that were installed along with `task-cinnamon-desktop`.

`tasksel --task-packages cinnamon-desktop` only lists [`task-cinnamon-desktop`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/task-cinnamon-desktop) because that is the package that the task installs; all the other packages are dependencies of `task-cinnamon-desktop`. You can see those either by clicking on the link above, or by using `apt show`, `apt-cache depends`, `apt-rdepends` etc. Note that the lists of packages you’ll find using this approach is somewhat theoretical: there are a large number of alternative dependencies, and which one is chosen will depend on what other packages are already installed.

*Ahead of time*, *i.e.* before a task is installed, you can determine what *would* be installed on a given system by asking `apt` what it would do:

```
apt install -s task-cinnamon-desktop
```

(this works without being root).

To determine what packages *could* be installed, theoretically, you need to explore the dependency tree. `apt-rdepends` will show you the maximal dependency tree, which isn’t very useful in this case. `apt show` will show you each package’s dependencies; starting with `task-cinnamon-desktop`:

```
$ apt show task-cinnamon-desktop
...
Depends: tasksel (= 3.53), task-desktop, cinnamon-desktop-environment
...
```

`tasksel` isn’t interesting, but this shows that `task-cinnamon-desktop` pulls in the main Cinnamon meta-package, [`cinnamon-desktop-environment`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/cinnamon-desktop-environment), and the general desktop task, [`task-desktop`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/task-desktop).

Continuing with the former:

```
$ apt show cinnamon-desktop-environment
...
Depends: cinnamon-core (>= 3.8), eog, evince | pdf-viewer, firefox-esr | firefox | chromium | iceweasel | gnome-www-browser, fonts-liberation, fonts-noto, gedit, gnome-calculator | galculator, gnome-screenshot, gnome-terminal | x-terminal-emulator, icedove | thunderbird | evolution | geary, pidgin | empathy, totem | gnome-mplayer | vlc, xdg-user-dirs-gtk
Recommends: blueman, brasero | k3b, cheese, cups, gdebi, gedit-plugins, gimp, gnome-disk-utility, gnome-font-viewer, gnome-games, orca | gnome-orca, gnome-sound-recorder, gnome-system-monitor, gnote, gstreamer1.0-libav, gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly, hexchat | xchat, inkscape, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-gnome, libreoffice-impress, libreoffice-writer, mate-themes, rhythmbox, rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder, rhythmbox-plugins, shotwell | gnome-photos, simple-scan, sound-juicer, sound-theme-freedesktop, synaptic, system-config-printer, transmission-gtk | deluge, vinagre, vino, yelp, zenity
...
```

The desktop environment depends on `cinnamon-core`, `eog`, a PDF viewer (`evince` by default), a web browser (`firefox-esr` by default), various fonts, `gedit`, etc. It also recommends a number of packages which will be installed by default but can be removed without removing the meta-package.

Comment: So by default also the recommended packages are installed. And `apt show [...] firefox-esr | firefox | chromium | iceweasel | gnome-www-browser` is `firefox-esr` and the rest are the alternatives.

Comment: Yes, recommended packages are installed by default, see the end of the answer ;-). Pipes separate alternatives, but all the packages are alternatives; the first one is the preferred package, *i.e.* the package which is installed by default if none of the alternatives are installed, and if the rest of the system allows it to be installed.

Comment: Curiously, I noticed that trying to get the source for the `task-xfce-desktop` package just has apt redirect me into only having the `tasksel` sources. How in the heck are these packages even made? It seems I don't get to know, at least not in any intuitive way.

Comment: @JohnTate [it’s defined in `tasksel`’s control file](https://salsa.debian.org/installer-team/tasksel/-/blob/edc9b2e20346279a10c48eeb750d0749fe7c19e2/debian/control#L265).